# PHP Upload - Spaces in File Name

Tags: php, apache, upload

When I use my upload script to upload a PHP file, I can't upload a file with spaces in it (I get a 500 error). Is there a way so my code automatically puts an underscore in the file name instead of the space? All help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: The code you posted does not seem to be completely relevant to what you demand

Comment: You need to show the code of real upload (with $_FILES) that said you can do a $filename = str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']); and use $filename

Comment: @Gabe Whoops; changed it

Comment: There is no code now.

Comment: @MarcoMura Okay, can I just have the PHP to do it then, not my code edited? :D

Comment: Well, php do upload the file? If the problem is the name of the file you can work around it. I think a better solution will be kick the user if the file has got spaces u_u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use **str_replace** to replace all white spaces with another string:

```
$fileName = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName);
```

- Doc: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

> Use this regular expression.suppose your filename look like my pic.jpg (one spaces) or my  pic.jpg (three spaces) would come out as my_pic.jpg (one underscores) or my___pic.jpg(three underscores).

```
$filename = 'my pic.jpg';   //your file name...
$filename = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $filename);

output : my_pic.jpg  //you get this output...
```