# Upload filenames with spaces in php

Tags: php, cgi

I am fairly new to PHP. I am trying to upload a file with spaces in the name [say "my file name.txt"] and pass the name to a cgi binary as argument.

`$fileName = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'];`

pass this filename as
`./myBin $fileName`
Now if I try getting the name inside 'myBin' say `printf("File name:%s", argv[1]);` , it would only print name before the space [here "my"]. How to get the whole name without modifying the file name that is uploaded ?. I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564501/php-upload-spaces-in-file-name#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=Simply%20use%20str_replace%20to%20replace,Doc%3A%20php.net) solution, which modifies the file name and not my requirement. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `./myBin '$fileName'`

Comment: This works. I missed that. Thank you @u_mulder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap parameter into quotes, e.g.:

```
./myBin '$fileName'
```